# ng-true-vale Non-Constant Expression

Tags: php, angularjs

i am printing checkbox value something following by php

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-false-value='' ng-true-value='$row->option'>
```

i am looping this dynamically,
but getting following error
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/constexpr?p0=ngTrueValue&p1=Canel

in html this `ng-true-value='$row->option'` printing like `ng-true-value="Canel"`
is there any way to do like this `ng-true-value="'Canel'"`, thats mean doublequte then single quote then value then single quote then double quote (something like `"'Canel'"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<input type='checkbox' ng-false-value='' ng-true-value=\"'$row->option'\">";
```

If `$row->option` is *test* it will output:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-false-value='' ng-true-value="'test'">
```

Comment: `"<input type='checkbox' ng-false-value='' ng-true-value=\"$row->option\">";` should be exclude single quote, anyways thanks